# start a group of radiobuttons unchecked in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, radio-button

Hólla everybody,

I have a strongly typed view and for one `int Rating` property, I am generating few radio buttons like so:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Rating, 1, new { id = "past_Rating_one"})
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Rating, 2, new { id = "past_Rating_two"})
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Rating, 3, new { id = "past_Rating_three"})
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Rating, 4, new { id = "past_Rating_four"})
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Rating, 5, new { id = "past_Rating_five"})
```

of course, I be having labels after each radio button and jquery be fancying it with images and such wonders.

All this is fine, but when the page starts, the radio button with id `past_Rating_one` be selected already. I be bewildered as to how to start all radio buttons unchecked when page loads.

Sure, can do with jQuery but I want to do it just with the view.

I tried it with this:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Rating, 1, new { id = "past_Rating_one", selected="none"})
```

firebug inspection shows that as a property, but still that darn radio button (first one) be stubbornly checked, so I thought I would seek yer help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try setting Rating as a nullable object in your viewmodel, like:

```
int? Rating { get; set; }
```

An integer defaults to zero, so value 0 will be selected when rendering the radiobuttons. I know in your example you don't use the value 0, but I suspect you do in your project. Otherwise I could not think of reason the radiobutton is selected.

In case Rating is an enum, the same thing applies.

Comment: Robin, you mention if it's an enum then the same thing applies. I get an error if I do `public MyEnum? MyProperty { get; set;}`. I am having the same problem with the first thing in my radio button list being default selected, and I want them to all be blank on page load. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @REMESQ I know this is old, but I am using an nullable Enum and it works perfectly for me.  What error are you getting?

Comment: @Rob Problem resolved. Instead of `int? Rating` for example, I might do `RatingEnum? Rating`.

Comment: What if I have an enum with 3 values, but I want to display only 2 rado buttons, and when none of the, is selected then I would expect the fisrt value form an enum: 'Enum X{ A,B,C}' radio button for B and for C, but none of the selected the model property would be value A